# Does tar create new inodes to be archived?

Tags: filesystems, tar, inode, file-metadata

When tar is asked to archive a directory, does it create a new inode for each file system object? If yes, how does it query and save the meta-data? Won't the format of storing this inode metadata vary from system to system? How does tar maintain a consistent output?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Maybe the downvote is because the question doesn't seem to make much sense. Why would creating an archive with tar creating inodes? It's creating an archive, not a filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

`tar` creates a single file (an inode). The format of a `tar` archive is standardized.

Comment: How does it get the attributes of the files to be archived?

Comment: @user1071840 I don't understand this question. As I don't understand the complete second half of your main question.

Comment: Sorry, for being confused and confusing. This is my dilemma.. 'Say I'm using file system A that stores file attributes in some format called 'X'. Now, I tar a directory on this file system 'A' and untar in on file system 'B' that uses a different format for storing inode attributes. Will I be able to see the original file meta-data from system 'A''? I want to understand how the metadata is tar'ed in the first place and how is it un-tar'ed.

Comment: @user1071840 Then you have to read the definition of the `tar` format. The metadata is restored via syscalls (see e.g. `man 2 chmod`). How the restoring system stores this information is not tar's problem.

Answer (score 0):

`tar` creates an archive, a single file that can contain many other files and objects. As such it will only consists of one relevant inode.

In the tar archive `tar` stores sequentially the meta data of each file in a header block followed by the contents of the file in data blocks. That header block contains the information you would typically associate with an inode, but it is left to the source and target file systems on how those actually store meta-data.

The header block contains (if available):

```
/* tar Header Block, from POSIX 1003.1-1990.  */  
/* POSIX header.  */

struct posix_header
{                              /* byte offset */
  char name[100];               /*   0 */
  char mode[8];                 /* 100 */
  char uid[8];                  /* 108 */
  char gid[8];                  /* 116 */
  char size[12];                /* 124 */
  char mtime[12];               /* 136 */
  char chksum[8];               /* 148 */
  char typeflag;                /* 156 */
  char linkname[100];           /* 157 */
  char magic[6];                /* 257 */
  char version[2];              /* 263 */
  char uname[32];               /* 265 */
  char gname[32];               /* 297 */
  char devmajor[8];             /* 329 */
  char devminor[8];             /* 337 */
  char prefix[155];             /* 345 */
                                /* 500 */
};
```